# Where does the chain rule come from for multivariable functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know how to use it to find derivatives like

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$ etc.

But I'm not exactly sure where it comes from can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: Well ... it's in every textbook that covers multivariable calculus.

Comment: I suppose [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) is a big high-level, but perhaps it could be a start.

Comment: Note that in your equation, two different functions are both called $ f $. I have always thought that's confusing, and it can be avoided by putting a hat over the $ f $ on the left.

Comment: Since the derivative represents the best linear approximation to the change in a function the change in the composition of two functions best linear approximations turns out to be the composite of the linear approximations whose formula in turn is represented by the matrix multiplication of the Jacobian matrices for the functions... hence the rule. Well, hence all the chain rules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here's a way to somewhat see it. If you assume $f$ is smooth, and change $x$ a little bit $\Delta x$ and $y$ a little bit $\Delta y$, then any change in $f$ that you get BESIDES the combination of $\Delta x f_x$ and $\Delta y f_y$ would have to be in terms of higher order derivatives with combined powers of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ that are higher than 1 (one way to see this is directly with Taylor expansions, but hopefully it makes some intuitive sense too, since by assumption the derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous, hence approximately constant over short changes in variable values). Thus if you have a parameter $u$ and change $u$ by a little bit $\Delta u$, then $x$ changes approximately an amount proportional to $\Delta u (dx/du)$ and similarly for $y$. This in turn gives you the approximate change for the function when you combine the effects of the estimated change in $x$ and the estimated change in $y$. Putting it all together and writing down a formula gives you the chain rule.